# Problem with RSA keys and signing process with EVP_DigestSign_* API - OpenSSL3.1.0

Tags: openssl, rsa, digital-signature

Currently I am working on the code refactoring to not use OpenSSL's 3.x deprecated functions. My OpenSSL version is 3.1.0.

I hit the wall because I cannot sign the message with EVP_DigestSign_* function because I get the error:

`error:40800066:lib(129)::cant get key.`

The RSA keypair is generated in the easiest way as shown below:
`rsaKeyPair = EVP_RSA_gen(2048);`

and the signing process:

```
        EVP_MD_CTX* ctxRSA = NULL;
        int rc;
        size_t sig_len = 0;
        unsigned char* sig = NULL;

        ctxRSA = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
        //ctxRSA = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
        if (ctxRSA == NULL)
        {
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err_buffer);
        }

        rc = EVP_DigestSignInit(ctxRSA, NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL, rsaKeyPair);
        if (rc != 1) 
        {
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err_buffer);
        }

        rc = EVP_DigestSignUpdate(ctxRSA, message, mSize);
        if (rc != 1) 
        {
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err_buffer);
        }

        if (1 != EVP_DigestSignFinal(ctxRSA, NULL, &sig_len))
        {

        }

        if (!(sig = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * sig_len)))
        {
            // error
        }

        // Need to be sure that user buffer is big enough to keep signature 
        if (signLength > 0 && CSA_SUCCESS == ret)
        {
            switch (EVP_DigestSignFinal(ctxRSA, sig, &sig_len))
            {
                case 1:
                    ret = CSA_SUCCESS;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err_buffer);
                    ret = CSA_ERROR;
                    break;
                default:
                    ret = CSA_ERROR;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LOG_ERROR("The size of signature's buffer is too small or signing error occured!");
            ret = CSA_ERROR;
        }
```

The same code but with EC keys works as expected.

`EVP_EC_gen(OSSL_EC_curve_nid2name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1));`

I am wondering what is wrong ? Is here anyone who have similar problem ?

MP

I tried different option for signing but still the same output for RSA keys. Interesting thing is that for EC keys everything work as expected.. I need to know if I missed smth or it is just kind of openssl bug.

Answer (score 0):

Other then your code will not compile as is, the code per say should work fine.
Here is a compilable example that compiles and runs fine that is pretty much the same as your code.  So there must be something else you are missing from your code that is causing the problem.

The code is c++ and was tested with openssl 3.1.1 with the MSVC compiler on windows.  But should work the same of other platforms fine as well.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

template<typename T, typename D>
std::unique_ptr<T, D> make_handle(T* handle, D deleter)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T, D>{handle, deleter};
}

bool test_rsa_gen_digest_sign()
{
    auto const evp_key = make_handle(EVP_RSA_gen(2048), EVP_PKEY_free);
    if(evp_key == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "EVP_EC_gen: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr) << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    auto const mdCtx = make_handle(EVP_MD_CTX_create(), EVP_MD_CTX_free);
    if (mdCtx == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "EVP_MD_CTX_create: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr) << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (EVP_DigestSignInit(mdCtx.get(), nullptr, EVP_sha256(), nullptr, evp_key.get()) != 1) 
    {
        std::cout << "EVP_DigestSignInit: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr) << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::string const message = "Hello world!";

    if (EVP_DigestSignUpdate(mdCtx.get(), message.c_str(), message.length()) != 1) 
    {
        std::cout << "EVP_DigestSignUpdate: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr) << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    size_t sig_len = 0;
    if (1 != EVP_DigestSignFinal(mdCtx.get(), nullptr, &sig_len))
    {
        std::cout << "EVP_DigestSignFinal: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr) << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::vector<uint8_t> sig(sig_len);
    if (1 != EVP_DigestSignFinal(mdCtx.get(), sig.data(), &sig_len))
    {
        std::cout << "EVP_DigestSignFinal: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr) << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    auto const result = test_rsa_gen_digest_sign();
    puts(result ? "\nsuccessful" :  "\nfailed");
}
```